# Google analytics with multiple subdomains

Tags: google-analytics

I've got a domain name lets call it `example.com`, which has multiple subdomains.

1. `blog.example.com`
2. `shop.example.com`
3. `press.example.com`
4. `site.example.com`

I'm trying to get these domains to all report properly in google analytics, first I'll share my current configuration then the issue that it caused.

**Current configuration:**

Under the `Tracking Code` tab in the admin.
What are you tracking? = One domain with multiple subdomains

[image: what are you tracking?]

The root domain, example.com's `profile` is set as follows.

[image]

A subdomain, blog.example.com's `profile` is set as follows.

[image]

These subdomain profiles show up all under one account like they should.

[image]

I am not using any filters, and I just tried to filter by subdomain and I can't get it to work, no matter what the content and the numbers are all the numbers for `example.com`.

**Problem with this configuration**

All of the profiles have the same data, the content from the root domain.

I previously was not using filters now I am one for each subdomain looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You just said that you're not using any filters. But in order to "filter" by subdomain you need to setup filters. So please show the filters you have setup in each profile.

Comment: I updated the question (at the bottom) with a screenshot of my filter, I set it up yesterday and it still does not work.

Comment: for some reason the profiles I had made that were not filtered, when I applied filters the numbers did not level out the data was still the root, I just deleted the subdomain profile and re-created them and the numbers zero'd out.

Comment: Filters don't work retroactively. So if you aplied the filters yesterday the data before that won't change. EVER. The data going forward will be ok.

Comment: thanks i think I should be good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously was not using filters now I am one for each subdomain looks like this:

[image]

Although I don't think this an issue with GA anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but setting up profiles could help as described here: http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the concept of "Accounts" and "Profiles" within Google Analytics.
Your account name is "Example site". If you want the data from subdomains in separate profiles, create separate accounts(not separate google accounts).
All profiles within the same account will have the same data.

Hint for you to find out account. All profiles within a folder group belong to the same account. Create separate top level folder groups.

Comment: I want all of the analytics javascript snippits to be identical under one "account". If I separate each subdomain into accounts not profiles I will have different code for each subdomain. I also want it to be easier to manage and all be under one account. I would say that this is not the way to do it filters and profiles for each subdomain is the way. I've updated the question (at the bottom) with my filter configuration and it does not seem to be working.

Comment: That's correct and recommended way of tracking multiple sites. Additionally you can use http://gachart.appointment.at/ to see the performance of your multiple accounts in one place.